# Get rectangle from GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter or GPUImageHoughTransformLineDetector

Tags: ios, ocr, augmented-reality, gpuimage

I am working on Business Card or Licence Card scanning in iOS. Before i use OpenCV but openCV is too slow for realtime card detection via camera. I switched to GPUImage open source library. The problem is how i can get rectangle from the four corner points using `GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter` or a rectangle area formed by lines crossing each other using `GPUImageHoughTransformLineDetector`